# T-SQL: Join three tables and limit to earliest encounter

Tags: sql-server

I'm fairly new to sql and have sunk  a whole day into trying to figure out how to do the following. I have 3 tables that look something like this:

Table 1
`customer_id    department_id    start_dts
      1              2           2011-07-23 14:30:00
      3              1           2011-07-24 10:15:00
      3              1           2011-08-18 11:14:00
      2              3           2012-05-04 05:45:00
      1              3           2010-06-09 15:20:00`

Table 2

`department_id    deparment_nm
      1              a
      2              b
      3              c`

Table 3

`customer_id    customer_nm
     1             betty
     2             fred
     3             dino`

I want to generate a list of the earliest encounter for each department and the associated customer name for the encounter such that it would look something like this (order of the dept doesn't matter):
`department_nm     customer_nm    start_dts
  a                 dino           2011-07-24 10:15:00 
  b                 betty          2011-07-23 14:30:00
  c                 betty          2010-06-09 15:20:00`

I first attempted to join table 2 on table 1 by department_id then inner joining table 3 on customer_id and using the min function for start_dts under the select statement, but that gives me each customers first encounter in each department.  I then tried various iterations of nested joins and attempted to use an over/partition clause to get what I want, but I don't think I'm understanding that concept correctly.  Any insight is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with cte as (
select dept_nm, cust_nm, row_number() over (partition by t1.dept_id order by start_dts) rn, start_dts from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
on t1.dept_id = t2.dept_id
left join table3 t3
on t1.cust_id = t3.cust_id
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Not sure i understood your requirement correctly.. but looks you are trying something like this...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sparse on actual details but something like this is what you are looking for. This has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times.

```
select department_nm
    , customer_nm
    , start_dts
from
(
    select department_nm
        , customer_nm
        , start_dts
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t1.customer_id, t1.department_id order by t1.start_dts desc) as RowNum
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t2.department_id = t1.department_id
    join table3 t3 on t3.customer_id = t1.customer_id
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: I dont think you want to partition by `customer_id`, he just wants the first customer to encounter the department.. and also order by start_dts ASC

Comment: Thanks both, very much.  Apologies for clogging things up with a question that's been asked many times before - I did search, but think I'm green enough at this that I probably wasn't searching very effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like CTEs and Window functions are overkill for something like this. The following should work, if I understood correctly.

```
SELECT department_nm, customer_nm, MIN(start_dts) AS [start_dts]
FROM
(
    SELECT department_nm, customer_nm, start_dts
    FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.department_id = t2.department_id
    JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
) x
GROUP BY department_nm, customer_nm
```